# "psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory"

Tags: debian, postgresql

Actually, I installed PostgreSQL 9.4 (with postGIS extension), and when installed, everything used to work fine.

As said on many tuts, I've set the /data folder, checked configuration files, and so on. Worked on other projects so I did not work on psql for a while But when installation was done, it used to work correctly, I made a test database, initialized postgres user, etc.

Now, I try to start psql (with "default" postgres user) and cannot connect! Start/stop/restart service do not change anything...

Result of "psql" command (with postgres user) :

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server  running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

When I check service status, I get this :

```
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled)
Active: active (exited) since tue 2016-05-24 09:24:13 CEST; 3s ago
Process: 5658 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 5658 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Starting/Stopping/Restarting service with command

```
sudo service postgresql start (or restart or stop)
```

Does not change anything to actual system behaviour..

Log says:

```
DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).
FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main" has group or world access
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On a debian system, postgresql files and directories should be owned by user `postgres`, in group `postgres`, with permissions of either `0700` (directories) or `0600` (files).

If they're not that, you can repair perms & ownership with:

```
sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/
sudo chmod -R u=rwX,go= /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/
```

Note the capital `X` in the `chmod` command.  Unlike a lowercase `x`, that will set the execute bit **only** on directories and on files that are *already* executable (there shouldn't be any of those in the pg directories).

and then restart the postgresql service.

Comment: And then restart the service command using `sudo service postgresql restart
`

Comment: Also if restarting service doesn't solve the problem for some, `sudo reboot`

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure your postgres server is running then try to login by specifying the host as localhost. When you say psql on its own it is attempting to use a socket to connect.

I had this issue when I upgraded Postgres and wanted to still access my old server. The new psql got confused.

Try:

```
psql -U username -h localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error messages right after a fresh installation of postgreSQL13 when running `psql` (both from the normal command prompt and after `sudo su - postgres`):

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

It turned out that I really just had to start the service, as it is also suggested by [How do I access Postgres when I get an error about “/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432”?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182189/how-do-i-access-postgres-when-i-get-an-error-about-var-run-postgresql-s-pgsql).

Try:

- `sudo systemctl start postgresql` (or use `enable` to start this at every startup, see [Getting started with PostgreSQL on Linux](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/postgresql-setup-use-cases)) or
- `sudo service postgresql start` (for example needed on WSL2).

Then:

```
sudo su - postgres
psql
```

and you are in.

Perhaps it helps someone. Your problem was probably different, though, since your server was already running.