# psql dump local to remote server: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql

```
psql -f alldb.sql postgres
```

output

> alldb.sql: No such file or directory

Already tried ["psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285080/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory)

and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653690/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-5432-error

No error in /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log

> 2019-07-01 22:00:53 IST [2514-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
>   2019-07-01 22:00:53 IST [2509-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept >connections
>   2019-07-01 22:00:53 IST [2517-1] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete >startup packet
>   2019-07-01 22:01:20 IST [2892-1] iitians@postgres FATAL:  role "iitians" >does not exist
>   2019-07-01 22:03:31 IST [2924-1] root@postgres FATAL:  role "root" does >not exist
>   2019-07-01 22:03:48 IST [2933-1] root@postgres FATAL:  role "root" does >not exist
>   2019-07-01 23:22:40 IST [4052-1] root@postgres FATAL:  role "root" does not >exist
>   2019-07-01 23:35:08 IST [2509-2] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
>   2019-07-01 23:35:08 IST [2509-3] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
>   2019-07-01 23:35:08 IST [2514-2] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
>   2019-07-01 23:35:08 IST [2511-1] LOG:  shutting down
>   2019-07-01 23:35:08 IST [2511-2] LOG:  database system is shut down
>   2019-07-01 23:35:09 IST [4176-1] LOG:  database system was shut down at >2019-07-01 23:35:08 IST
>   2019-07-01 23:35:09 IST [4176-2] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound >protections are now enabled
>   2019-07-01 23:35:09 IST [4180-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
>   2019-07-01 23:35:09 IST [4175-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept >connections
>   2019-07-01 23:35:09 IST [4182-1] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete >startup packet

Comment: Don't you think you should ask a proper question instead of only dumping some unformatted logs here?

Comment: U mean to say this was proper https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285080/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory but i tried all it didnt solved. If u want u can block the account

Comment: Your error is `alldb.sql: No such file or directory`, which indicates that the `psql` command you ran could not find the file `alldb.sql` which you indicated with the `-f` flag.  Is there a file `alldb.sql` in the directory you are running the `psql` command?  Where is this file?

Comment: alldb.sql is in my local machine under /users/jagtarsingh/ which i want to dump to remote server i have logged in as superuser postgres